# Can't change the color of grid lines in apexchart

Tags: apexcharts

As shown in the image below I'm trying to change the colors of the yaxix lines or border lines.

[image: here]

This is what I'm trying:

```
        grid: {
            borderColor: "#90A4AE",
            color: '#D0D4D9',
            yaxis: { 
                color: '#D0D4D9',
                borderColor: "#ffffff4f",
                lines: {
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff4f",
                    borderColor: "#ffffff4f",
                        style: {
                            color: '#D0D4D9',
                            borderColor: "#ffffff4f",
                        },
                }
            }, 
        },
```

But can't change the color of the lines (as they are blue-ish in the above image). I'm not sure what is the issue but I’m pretty sure they are grid lines and this should change the colors.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [borderColor](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/grid/) alone is enough to change the gridline colors. The example below will set the gridlines to red:

```
options = {
  ...
  grid: {
    borderColor: "#ff0000",
  },
  ...
}
```

The default color for the gridlines is the same as you've put, `#90A4AE`, which maybe why you're not seeing a change in the color.

Comment: I tried but no results, then i tried in codepen and worked like a charm. so i guess somewhere in my code i'm changing the color somehow but i checked every single file, can't figure this one little thing out. i've spent couple hours on this and can't figure out the issue. is there any other way you can think of to change the grid border colors? frustrated tbh.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. I would recommend stripping away everything that isn't necessary, setting the border color as you want, and then adding it back bits one at a time to see if it affects the border color.

Comment: @Thematador did you find the solution? i'm facing the same problem